# Using get_permalink inside functions.php return 1

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a function in my wordpress theme:

```
function ajax_get_videoposts () {

$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);
//get 5 posts which are published
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);

$append .= '<div id="recommended-videos" class="recommended-videos rec-vid rec-vid2">';
$append .= '<div class="rec-title">Check These Out Next:</div>';
$append .= '<div class="rec-videos">';

foreach ($recent_posts as $recent) {
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($recent['ID']);
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url($thumb_id);
    $append .= '<div class="videos">';
    //a hrefs
    $append .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">';
    $append .= '<div class="videoinfo">' . (__($recent["post_title"])) . '</div>' . '</a>';
    //img tag
    $append .= '<img align="top"' . 'src="' . $url . '"' . 'alt="' . (__($recent["post_title"])) . '">';
    //looping 6 times
    $append .= '</div>';
}

$append .= '<div class="rec-btns">';
$append .= print_r(get_permalink());

echo $append;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_get_videoposts', 'ajax_get_videoposts' );    // If called from admin panel
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_get_videoposts', 'ajax_get_videoposts' );    // If called from front end
```

Then I call this function i call this function via AJAX. The problem is
 `$append .= print_r(get_permalink());`
Printing me the number '1' instead of the post URL because it is used in the functions.php instead of for example single.php how would i get the post URL inside functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

Why using print_r ?

Isn't

```
$append = get_permalink();
```

what you really want?

Just in case, if you want to store print_r inside a variable, then you must pass TRUE as a second parameter. That will give us :

```
$append = print_r(get_permalink(),TRUE);
```

Comment: print_r was for test purpse because get_permalink(); was returning nothing. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect `get_permalink()` to return anything useful, given that you're calling this function via Ajax, and from what can be seen of your code a loop isn't in play.  It's not clear from looking at this code which page or post you were hoping `get_permalink()` would be referring to; perhaps sharing your reason for doing this will help in providing a better answer.

Also, the '1' output you see is because of how `print_r` works:

> When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the return value is **TRUE**.

Your `$append .= print_r(get_permalink());` effectively resolves to `$append .= TRUE;` (which in being string-concatenated will be cast to the string representation `'1'`).

Comment: The AJAX is just posting HTML over a DIV and the get_permalink was used in the function just to return a href with the link. so the only way is via jQuery?